# Generate constructor for required super fields

Tags: java, lombok

I've the following class:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public abstract class EmailData {

    private final Iterable<String> recipients;
}
```

and the following subclass:

```
import lombok.Getter;

@Getter
public class PasswordRecoveryEmail extends EmailData {

    private final String token;
}
```

Is there any possibility to annotate `PasswordRecoveryEmail` in such a way that a constructor for both required class and superclass fields will be generated?

Comment: Lombok doing this would be helpful for Spring projects that autowires on constructor parameters.

Comment: @marcioggs as far as I remember this was a spring-motivated question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `@…Constructor` annotations will not explicitly call a constructor, so they all rely on a default constructor doing a proper job. So, no, you cannot convince Lombok to create these constructors for you.

The closest you can get it is to either:

1. Provide a default constructor (no arguments) in `EmailData` that is `protected` and assigns some reasonable value to `recipients`.
2. Write the required-args constructor for `PasswordRecoveryEmail` yourself.

Inheritance often is not quite covered by Lombok in my experience.

Comment: Still seems to be true. `In the case of inheritance, Lombok can’t generate automatically a constructor that calls a super constructor with parameters for a subclass.` https://devwithus.com/lombok-constructor-annotations/ (as last part)

Comment: Interestingly, Kotlin’s data classes face a similar dilemma.